# Problem with woocommerce_add_order_item_meta replacement code

Tags: woocommerce

I previously had this code to add custom field values to the Order and Order emails. This worked and still works but I'm getting errors in the error log due to the code being depreciated:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_item_meta', 10, 2);
function add_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {
if ( empty( $values['_goodlen'] ) ) {
return;
}
woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Flavours', $values['_goodlen'] );
}
```

I've replaced it with:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_item_meta', 10, 2);
function add_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {
if ( empty( $values['_goodlen'] ) ) {
return;
}
woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item_id, 'Flavours', $values['_goodlen'] );
}
```

But that no longer adds the content to the email and orders.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I may have answered my question. Been looking around for ages and found this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get a product custom field value
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_goodlen', true );
    // Update order item meta
    if( isset( $values['_goodlen'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'Flavours', $values['_goodlen'] );
    }
}
```

Seems to work and display in both order and order email and doesn't throw up any errors in the log.